# No alive nodes found in your cluster error - Elasticsearch

Tags: php, elasticsearch, nginx

I'm using `laravel 8` and `elasticsearch`. But sometimes I got this error message:

```
no alive nodes found in your cluster `elasticsearch`
```

I don't know what is problem. It happened 3 times last week.

I suggest I must restart `elasticsearch`, but I think this isn't a solution.
my server is `nginx`.

Comment: This message means that your application could not connect to any elasticsearch in your cluster named `elasticsearch`. You need to investigate in your elasticsearch nodes what is causing this issue, look at the logs in the server.